# How do I export and host a ggvis chart on my own webserver?

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

As I understand ggvis runs on top of shiny. But I can't figure out how to export all the files needed for running a single ggvis chart on a webserver without R/shiny.

Answer (score 6):

That won't be possible for interactive plots since *"every interactive ggvis plot must be connected to a running R session"* (via [ggivs basics](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/ggvis-basics.html)). However, it is possible with ones that don't require reactive values.

**CAVEAT** ggvis is still rly new, so YMMV with 0.2.x for the following+.

I gave the various ggvis/knitr print functions a quick try but didn't manage to generate the whole document (i.e with the necessary libraries). If you do invoke a standard, non-interactive ggvis with something like:

```
library(ggvis)
p <- ggvis(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg)
p
```

and do a "view in browser", you'll see that the directory it creates has a main HTML file and a `libs` directory. You'll need all those javascript libraries in your site and then an outer template like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/d3-3.4.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/vega-1.3.3/vega.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/lodash-2.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>var lodash = _.noConflict();</script>
<link href="lib/ggvis-0.3.0.99/css/ggvis.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/ggvis-0.3.0.99/js/ggvis.js"></script>
<script src="lib/shiny-ggvis-0.3.0.99/js/shiny-ggvis.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

You can get the ggvis plot HTML via:

```
library(knitr)
q <- knit_print.ggvis(p)
writeLines(as.character(q), "~/SOMEDIR/ggvis.html")
```

and then just insert it in the `body` tag.

If you poke around a bit more at the ggvis source at github, you might be able to figure out how to use `view_static` (from ggvis) to get it to this automatically. I'm also pretty sure that there's a way to knit from an rmarkdown file directly to html, but I'm kinda staying clear of ggvis until at least 0.4/0.5 for pseudo-production vis.