# Save ggvis html to file

Tags: html, r, plot, data-visualization, ggvis

**Goal:**

I would like to be able to create static ggvis plots and pass a parameter for a directory path where the html file is saved.

**Mock Data:**

```
require(ggvis)

# Create mock data to work with
dfa <- data.frame(
date_a = seq(from= as.Date("2015-06-10"), 
    to= as.Date("2015-07-01"), by= 1),
val_a = c(2585.150, 2482.200, 3780.186, 3619.601, 
    0.000, 0.000, 3509.734, 3020.405, 
    3271.897, 3019.003, 3172.084, 0.000, 
    0.000, 3319.927, 2673.428, 3331.382, 
    3886.957, 2859.887, 0.000, 0.000, 
    2781.443, 2847.377) )
```

**Example plot:**

Here is an example of a static ggvis plot.

```
# Create working static ggvis plot
dfa %>%
  ggvis( x= ~date_a , y= ~val_a, stroke := "black", opacity := 0.5 ) %>% 
    scale_datetime("x", nice = "month", domain = c(as.Date("2015-06-10"),
    as.Date("2015-07-15") )) %>%
    layer_lines() %>% layer_points( fill := "black" )
```

When this is run, by default the html file is written to `"file:///C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpyuMDDO/viewhtml1bf039815bb2/index.html"`.  Instead, I would like to be able to pass a desired path:  `"file:///C:/my/desired/path/to/plot/index.html"` as a parameter and have the html file saved there.

**Research:**

Here are some related topics that I have read but was not able to make work:

[Documentation](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/blob/master/R/print.R)

[SO Discussion on saving html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344317/how-do-i-export-and-host-a-ggvis-chart-on-my-own-webserver)

With respect to the previous SO discussion, first has there been further development since this older post, and second, I would prefer to just pass a destination path and have the html written to the specified path.

Comment: _"dest Deprecated (this no longer works)."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this into `output.Rmd`:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggvis)
dfa <- data.frame(
date_a = seq(from= as.Date("2015-06-10"),
    to= as.Date("2015-07-01"), by= 1),
val_a = c(2585.150, 2482.200, 3780.186, 3619.601,
    0.000, 0.000, 3509.734, 3020.405,
    3271.897, 3019.003, 3172.084, 0.000,
    0.000, 3319.927, 2673.428, 3331.382,
    3886.957, 2859.887, 0.000, 0.000,
    2781.443, 2847.377) )

dfa %>%
  ggvis( x= ~date_a , y= ~val_a, stroke := "black", opacity := 0.5 ) %>%
    scale_datetime("x", nice = "month", domain = c(as.Date("2015-06-10"),
    as.Date("2015-07-15") )) %>%
    layer_lines() %>% layer_points( fill := "black") %>% 
  knit_print.ggvis(inline=TRUE)
```
````

At an R console (in the proper directory), run:

```
rmarkdown::render("output.Rmd")
```

And `output.html` will look like:

[image]

and be a standalone document.

If you work a bit, you can make this a function that does what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  While wrapping this in an Rmarkdown document works, it seems like there should be a way to specify the destination of the ggvis output HTML.  I will accept this as a solution if no other alternatives are presented.  Again, thank you for the suggestion.